# Who should implement the concurrency - the client or the server

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In my application I have the following potentially long running classes:

- ScheduleLocalNotificationsOperation
- UnScheduleLocalNotificationsOperation
- SyncEventsToDeviceCalendarOperation
- UnSyncEventsToDeviceCalendarOperation
- SaveProductsToLocalStorageImpl

and so on.

Most of these are structured this way:

```
public interface Operation {
    void execute();
}

public class ScheduleLocalNotificationsOperation implements Operation {

    private MyApplication application;
    private List<LocalNotificationDescriptor> localNotifications;

    public ScheduleLocalNotificationsOperation (MyApplication application, List<LocalNotificationDescriptor> localNotifications) {
        this.application = application;
        this.localNotifications = localNotifications;
    }


    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // Do some stuff
    }

}
```

Ideally, I would like to design my Operation classes to be concurrency agnostic, and to be able to impose some multithreading policy on them from the outside, like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        executorService.submit(new Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ScheduleLocalNotificationsOperation(application, createLocalNotificationsList()).execute();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

But this way I should implement some concurrency policy in every client, every time I call those classes.

On the other hand, I dont want to interrupt the pure logic in those operations by adding concurrency to them, so my question is basically, from design stand point what is the better way to do this, if there is a clearly defined one?

Can I create an `OperationsRunner` class that will be called by any client and will execute any `Operation` using polymorphism and make that class be the only one that deals with concurrency?

Comment: always server, and client if it needs it too.

Comment: So you are saying I should put concurrency code in each Operation and then call them from the main thread in the clients?

Comment: Can I create an OperationsRunner class that will be called by any client and will execute any Operation using polymorphism and make that class be the only one that deals with concurrency?

Comment: I would answer in more detail, but I *think* this is more of a code-review type question; to be asked on the sister forum. That said, it's not worth a downvote, in my opinion.

Comment: So if I post it there instead, I would get an answer, and possibly no downvotes?

Comment: Are you saying that I should not include concurrency anywhere, but if I had to do those tasks concurrently, where should I put the concurrency logic/policy?